# Get Row number of excel using ADO

Tags: sql, excel, vbscript, adodb, vba

We are trying to get the row number of particular recordset retreived based on soome condtion. consider below table

```
Name    Id
abc     1
cde     2
efg     3
```

Now, how to get the row number or recordset number of employee "cde" (accrding to below code we need to get the result as 2). Any help on this please.

```
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H0001
strSource="C:\Test.xls"
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strSource          & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"  
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")   
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
conn.Open strConnection 
objRecordset.Open "Select Name FROM [sheet1$] Where Id = 2", conn, adOpenStatic,     adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
msgbox objRecordset.GetString
conn.Close 
Set conn = Nothing
```

Comment: Try something like this: `Debug.Print UBound(objRecordset.GetRows,2) +1` which gives you number of all rows in your recordset. Put it before: `msgbox objRecordset.GetString`

Comment: Couldn't you get all the records in an array from recordset and loop through it to get the row number? How big is that table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to put a column in the Excel file that has the same data as the row number. Then query on that column. That is a fool-proof solution.

However, if for some reason you can't do that, then try this:

```
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H1
Dim RowNumber 
Dim SqlStmt 

strSource = "C:\Temp\Test.xls"
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strSource & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
conn.Open strConnection

SqlStmt = "Select Name, Id FROM [sheet1$]"      ''-- you can optimize this query if your Id is in ascending order. e.g. "Select Name, Id FROM [sheet1$] Where Id <= 4"
objRecordset.Open SqlStmt, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
objRecordset.Find "Id = 4"
RowNumber = objRecordset!ID + 1  ''-- +1 for Header row.
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing

MsgBox RowNumber
```