# Simplify TSQL statement to avoid "too complex" exception in VB.NET, OLEDB

Tags: vb.net, t-sql, oledb

I'd like to rewrite the following SQL statement to avoid exception `Expression too complex in query expression`. Sense of the expression is to find a specific row number in an Excel data sheet (using VB.NET, second row in this case, excluding headlines). Only 26 ORs are accepted. I tried it in many different ways, including nested SQL statements, but haven't found a solution yet (Is there a way to fulfill the condition with nested SQL?). Thank you very much!

Simplified: `SELECT ... WHERE ... OR ... OR ... OR ... ...` (too many ORs)

```
`SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Daten$] 
WHERE [Ab] NOT IN (SELECT TOP 1 [Ab] FROM [Daten$]) 
OR [Abgrenzungsgrund] NOT IN (SELECT TOP 1 [Abgrenzungsgrund] FROM [Daten$]) 
OR [Abrechnungsmenge] NOT IN (SELECT TOP 1 [Abrechnungsmenge] FROM [Daten$]) 
OR [Abschl 01] NOT IN (SELECT TOP 1 [Abschl 01] FROM [Daten$])
OR ...` (and so on)
```

connection string (if relevant): `"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='foo.xlsx';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;"`

Any idea? Thank you in advance!

Is there a simple way to automatically pass the result values of the sql subqueries as parameters? I found out that parameterized queries allow much more conditions.

Comment: NOT IN only works with single fields as I know. If I'm wrong, could you post an example, pseudo code?

Comment: Have you considered the method suggested in [Get Row number of excel using ADO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16087971/1115360): add a column with the row number and query on that, e.g. `SELECT * FROM [Daten$] WHERE [RowNum] = 2`?

Comment: Yes, I did, thank you. But I'm trying to find a solution in pure SQL.

Comment: Are you just trying to return the nth row of a dataset in an excel sheet using sql?

Comment: Yes, I do .....

Answer (score 0):

UNION all of the Abschl sets together, and do a single NOT IN on the result.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Daten$] 
WHERE [Ab] NOT IN
    (SELECT TOP 1 [Abgrenzungsgrund] FROM [Daten$]
     UNION SELECT TOP 1 [Abrechnungsmenge] FROM [Daten$]
     UNION SELECT TOP 1 [Abschl 01] FROM [Daten$] ...)
```

Comment: But what about the other fields? None of the columns has distinct values.

Comment: Your original query doesn't contain any "other" fields.

Comment: The gist is to somehow create a single data set for your WHERE NOT IN clause to compare against.

Comment: I tried it. It seems to be incorrect TSQL. Exception: "This operation is not allowed in subqueries."

Comment: Then you may need to try a Common Table Expression or create a temporary table that holds the result of the UNIONs.

Comment: Now I understood "UNION". But I think, that approach makes no sense because every column value has to be compared with values of its own column to make sure to reject the correct rows. Damn Microsoft!

Comment: T-SQL does have a Row_Number() function.  Perhaps you should check that out.

Comment: Thank you, but doesn't work in this case (only MS SQL Server and other) and you have to order the recordsets before and don't get the physically line number in Excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You could return all the rows, then use LINQ to skip and take the first element.

```vb
Sub Main()
    Dim result = getNthRow(3)
    Console.WriteLine(result)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Private Function getNthRow(n As Integer) As Daten
    Dim result As Daten
    If n < 1 Then Throw New ArgumentException("Row number must be 1 or greater", NameOf(n))
    Dim connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='foo.xlsx';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;"
    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Using connection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        connection.Open()
        Using command = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Daten$]", connection)
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            Using dataset As New DataSet()
                adapter.Fill(dataset)
                ' exception here if n too large
                Dim datarow = dataset.Tables(0).AsEnumerable.Skip(n - 1).First()
                result = New Daten With {
                    .Ab = CInt(datarow.Field(Of Double)("Ab")),
                    .Abgrenzungsgrund = datarow.Field(Of String)("Abgrenzungsgrund"),
                    .Abrechnungsmenge = datarow.Field(Of String)("Abrechnungsmenge"),
                    .Abschl01 = datarow.Field(Of String)("Abschl 01"),
                    .Abschl02 = datarow.Field(Of String)("Abschl 02"),
                    .Abschl03 = datarow.Field(Of String)("Abschl 03"),
                    .Abschl04 = datarow.Field(Of String)("Abschl 04"),
                    .Abschl05 = datarow.Field(Of String)("Abschl 05")}
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    Return result
End Function
```

Here is the class for your result so it can be strongly typed. You should modify the properties and types to more accurately represent your data

```vb
Class Daten
    Public Property Ab As Integer
    Public Property Abgrenzungsgrund As String
    Public Property Abrechnungsmenge As String
    Public Property Abschl01 As String
    Public Property Abschl02 As String
    Public Property Abschl03 As String
    Public Property Abschl04 As String
    Public Property Abschl05 As String
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{Ab}, {Abgrenzungsgrund}, {Abrechnungsmenge}, {Abschl01}, {Abschl02}, {Abschl03}, {Abschl04}, {Abschl05}"
    End Function
End Class
```